# Convert VARIANT to...?

Tags: c++, windows, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, com

**Note:**

- Attempting to invoke a method of an interface, of which the return type is `_variant_t`

**Code:**

```
_variant_t resultsDataString;

_bstr_t simObjectNames;

simObjectNames = SysAllocString (L"TEST example 3");

resultsDataString = pis8->GetSimObject (simObjectNames);
```

inline function **illustrated** below, contained in **.tli** FILE:

```
inline _variant_t IS8Simulation::GetSimObject ( _bstr_t Name ) {
    VARIANT _result;
    VariantInit(&_result);
     HRESULT _hr = get_SimObject(Name, &_result);
   if (FAILED(_hr)) _com_issue_errorex(_hr, this, __uuidof(this));
    return _variant_t(_result, false);
}
```

**Note:**

- `resultsDataString` is of **`struct` `tagVARIANT`**:

  - **`VARTYPE vt`** is 9 (unsigned short)
  - **`IDispatch`** IDispatch interface pointer

**Question**

- How can I then **convert** or **extract** the value?
- Possible using [VariantChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221258.aspx)?
- Another way?

### Edit:

**Note:**

- Looking to transform the following, Visual Basic code to Visual C++
- MFC or ATL, if need be
- Ideally, pure C++

**Visual basic** equivalent:

```
Public example1, example2 As SIMUL8.S8SimObject
Dim numberOfexamples As Variant
Dim resultString As Variant

Set example1 = MySimul8.SimObject("Example 1")
Set example2 = MySimul8.SimObject("Example 2")

numberOfexamples = example1.CountContents + example2.CountContents

resultString = CStr(numberOfexamples) & "*"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are using C++ as a COM client by relying on the VC++ compiler's built-in COM support. To make coding the client "easier" you've used `#import` to generate C++ wrapper classes that attempt to hide all the COM details from you - or at least make the COM details simpler. So you're *not* using the COM SDK directly, but are using a client-side framework (I think of it like a light-weight COM-only framework akin to ATL or MFC).

Your example code, however, seems to be mixing the direct low-level COM SDK (`VARIANT`s, `BSTR`, `SysAllocString`) with the `#import` COM framework (`_variant_t`, `_bstr_t`, `XXXXPtr`). COM from C++ is complicated at first - so in a perfect world I would suggest getting to know the basics of COM before going too far forward.

However, if you just want something to work I would ***guess*** this is `#import`-style-of-COM-clients version of the VB code you provided:

```
_variant_t example1Var;
_variant_t example1Var;
SIMUL8::S8SimObjectQIPtr example1; // I'm guessing at this type-name from the VB code
SIMUL8::S8SimObjectQIPtr example2;

example1Var = pis8->GetSimObject(_bstr_t(L"Example 1"));
example2Var = pis8->GetSimObject(_bstr_t(L"Example 2"));
if (example1Var.vt == VT_DISPATCH && example2Var.vt == VT_DISPATCH)
{
   // **UPDATE** to try to spoon feed the QI ptr...
   example1 = IDispatchPtr((IDispatch*)example1Var);
   example2 = IDispatchPtr((IDispatch*)example2Var);
   // Does this screw-up reference counting?

   int numberOfexamples = example1->CountContents + example2->CountContents;

}
```

**UPDATE:**
[Documentation on `#import`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6(VS.71).aspx) This makes using COM from C++ much easier, but is yet one other thing to learn...

Comment: ::S8SimObject *example1, *example2;

 resultsDataString = pis8->GetSimObject (simObjectNames);

 if (resultsDataString.vt == VT_DISPATCH)
 {
  example1 = (IDispatch *) resultsDataString;

  total_results example1->CountContents; 
 }

Comment: Please excuse my lack of knowledge...: 

error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'IDispatch *' to 'S8SimObject *'

Comment: I think you'd want to use the #import smart pointers vs. a raw interface pointer. The smart pointers have "Ptr" appended to the end. #import also creates fancier versions of the smart pointer that will query interface for you on the = operator. ("QIPtr")

Comment: Does a variable called S8SimObjectQIPtr compile?

Comment: You might need to do something like: example1Var.QueryInterface(__uuidof(IS8SimObject), &example1);

Comment: I was under the impression that the "QI" smart pointer would work. Maybe the equal operator requires a smartpointer r-value. I'll edit my answer with another idea.

Comment: I try to keep the "real" com stuff from leaking thru the #import abstraction if possible... this is why I'm avoiding QueryInterface.

Comment: @Aardvark: S8SimObjectQIPtr  does not compile. Regarding import: #import "S8.tlb" no_namespace

Comment: error C2039: 'QueryInterface' : is not a member of '_variant_t'

Comment: try ((IDispatch*)example1Var)->QueryInterface

Comment: Works now:

_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IS8SimObject, __uuidof(IS8SimObject));

 IS8SimObjectPtr example1;

Comment: @Aardvark && @crashmstr: Thanks for all your help guys :)!!!!!!!! - ummm where can I learn more about this stuff???

Comment: "Inside Distributed COM" from Microsoft Press and "Essential COM" from Don Box were the two books I learned from. Both are over 10 years old, but not much has changed as far as I can tell.

Comment: Inside COM - Rogerson (Microsoft Press) is great for the basics. The books crashmstr mentions are good as well. I'll add a link to the answer for what "#import" brings to the table...

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the MSDN docs for [_variant_t](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x295h94e.aspx)

There is a [ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kc812h8.aspx) method as well as [Extractors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0bcz27.aspx).

**Edit:** Once you have an `IDispatch` pointer, you need to use `QueryInterface` to get a specific object type with members and methods, or use `IDispatch::Invoke`. You can look at the MSDN Docs for `IDispatch`. Either way, you need to know about the object type that is being returned by the `IS8Simulation::GetSimObject` call.

**Edit #2:** Based on your VB code update, you want to use the same kind of code for C++, i.e. use the `S8SimObject` type in its C++ form (look in the generated .tlh file for `_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF`). Then you can directly do the same thing with `CountContents`. Otherwise, you would need to look up the `CountContents` DISPID with `IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames` and then call invoke.

Comment: Once the IDispatch interface pointer is extracted, is it possible to extract a value: some string, int etc...?

Comment: pDispatch->Invoke (DISPID_VALUE, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET | DISPATCH_METHOD, &dispParamsNoArgs, &varResolved, NULL, NULL); - varResolved is "Empty"???

Comment: Did Invoke return S_OK, or an error value? And make sure your parameters are all correct. The first parameter looks fishy. Use IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames to get the IDs based on string names of the properties.

Comment: hresult return "Member not found"

Comment: @crashmstr: What parameter values would you recommend? regards

Comment: I just updated my answer. You need to do a lookup of the ID (first parameter) using IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames

Comment: Hopefully there is a "dual" interface here - using IDispatch::Invoke directly is really, really ugly (as you've noticed).

Comment: No kidding. Thankfully, I never had to do anything directly with Invoke. But either way, MS made COM client development a whole lot cleaner and easier with VB than with C++.

Comment: IS8SimObject *pS8SimObject;

 hresult = pIClassFactory->CreateInstance(
           NULL,
           __uuidof(IS8SimObject),
           (LPVOID *)&pS8SimObject);

Comment: struct __declspec(uuid("f049c9d1-9ca6-4a70-bcdf-13e66fae659d"))
/* dual interface */ IS8Simulation;
struct /* coclass */ S8SimObject;.........?

Comment: @crashmstr Yeah VB6 was a super simple COM client. .NET COM support completely went off the rails IMOHO. I always liked using MIDL generated headers with ATL smart points. (I can't decide about #import... it's good and bad)

Comment: Also you may want to check that IDispatchPtr((IDispatch*)example2Var) will correctly reference count. You get +1 with the cast operator, not sure about the ctor of the IDispatchPtr?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to *convert* the `_variant_t`. It contains an `IDispatch` interface pointer, so you can get it out like this:

```
if (v.vt == VT_DISPATCH)
{
    IDispatchPtr pDispatch = v.pdispVal;
    // Do something with pDispatch.
    // e.g. assign it to a strongly-typed interface pointer.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept of "value" for an object (DISPID_VALUE).

Here is a [codeproject.com article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/resolving_variants.aspx) on resolving VARIANTs that might help.