# A simple way to convert to/from VARIANT types in C++

Tags: windows, visual-c++, variant

Are there any **easy-to-use**, **high-level classes or libraries** that let you interact with `VARIANT`s in Visual C++?

More specifically, I'd like to convert between POD types (e.g. `double`, `long`), strings (e.g. `CString`), and containers (e.g. `std::vector`) and `VARIANT`s.   For example:

```
long val = 42;
VARIANT var;
if (ToVariant(val, var)) ...     // tries to convert long -> VARIANT
comObjPtr->someFunc(var);

std::vector<double> vec;
VARIANT var = comObjPtr->otherFunc();
if (FromVariant(var, vec)) ...   // tries VARIANT -> std::vector<double>
```

I (naively?) assumed that people working with COM do this all the time, so there would most likely be a *single convenient library* that handles all sorts of conversions.  But all that I've been able to find is a motley assortment of wrapper classes that each convert a few types:

- [_variant_t](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x295h94e(VS.80).aspx) or [CComVariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac97df2h(VS.80).aspx) for POD types
- [_bstr_t](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6(VS.80).aspx), [CComBSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh7x9w3f.aspx), or [BSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221069.aspx) for strings
- [CComSafeArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xzbsee8(VS.80).aspx) or [SAFEARRAY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221482.aspx) for arrays

Is there any simple way -- short of switching to Visual Basic -- to avoid this nightmare of awkward memory management and bitwise `VT_ARRAY | VT_I4` code?

Related questions:

- [CComVariant vs. _variant_t, CComBSTR vs. _bstr_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288834/ccomvariant-vs-variant-t-ccombstr-vs-bstr-t)
- [Convert VARIANT to...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606527/convert-variant-to)
- [How to best convert VARIANT_BOOL to C++ bool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886729/how-to-best-convert-variant-bool-to-c-bool)

Comment: The question doesn't really apply to [c++] (which does not have that construct), just the visual dialect.

Comment: For anyone who is curious what POD means here is a stack overflow answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, most of the hard work is already done for you with the various wrapper classes.  I prefer _variant_t and _bstr_t as they are more suited for conversion to/from POD types and strings.  For simple arrays, all you really need is template conversion function.  Something like the following:

```
// parameter validation and error checking omitted for clarity
template<typename T>
void FromVariant(VARIANT Var, std::vector<T>& Vec)
{
    CComSafeArray<T> SafeArray;
    SafeArray.Attach(Var.parray);
    ULONG Count = SafeArray.GetCount();
    Vec.resize(Count);
    for(ULONG Index = 0; Index < Count; Index++)
    {
        Vec[Index] = SafeArray[Index];
    }
}
....
std::vector<double> Vec;
VARIANT Var = ...;
FromVariant(Var, Vec);
...
```

Of course things get hairy (in regards to memory / lifetime management) if the array contains non-POD types, but it is still doable.

Comment: Thanks -- that's useful, and pretty much what I've resigned myself to doing.  Like you say, what's missing is non-POD support, and perhaps type checking/coercion (e.g. convert a variant of doubles to a vector of ints).