# convert VARIANT to unsigned char array

Tags: c++, visual-c++, variant

I'm using Comm32 (an activeX control) to get data coming through serial port using the method GetInput().
This method returns a _variant_t, so I need to convert it to an array of unsigned char's.

When serial port is configured to TextMode (this is data input is interpreted as String), converting the Variant to a BSTR and then to a CString works as expected (code not writed by me):

```
_variant_t x = m_comm32.GetInput();
CString cs = x.bstrVal;
```

However, as data sent through serial port is actually binary data, when configuring comm32 to interpret data as binary the sample code above doesn't give me the valid data.
So I think I need to convert it to another format (unsigned char array maybe? that's somehting I want to test).

My problem is I'm getting crazy as I cannot find any detailed info about how to convert data from a VARIANT structure. How can I convert the variant to an unsigned char array??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **InputMode** property determines the type of data that is retrieved with the Input property. If InputMode is set to comInputModeText then the Input property returns text data in a Variant. If InputMode is comInputModeBinary then the Input property returns binary data in an array of bytes in a Variant. (from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259416%28v=VS.60%29.aspx))

To understand how to get data from the safearray see examples [sample1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359065/a-simple-way-to-convert-to-from-variant-types-in-c) or [sample2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177912)